# OpenCV and Low latency streaming on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm using my Raspberry Pi for object tracking with OpenCV and the Raspberry Pi camera. Latency is king here. I have tried using web-server based solutions which do have low latency, but it is not clear to me how to combine this with the tracking solution, CMT, which is written in Python, while the web server is written in C++. In addition, I'm hoping to avoid any lag I can when overlaying the algorithm's result on the video so that the already slow algorithm won't be noticeably slower.

In short, I would like to do CMT analysis on realtime video from a Raspberry Pi camera, overlay it on the video, and stream it over wifi to the user. Is this possible within the constraint of relatively low latency (over two seconds is unusable)?

Comment: I'd say your best bet is doing as much as possible on the server side. That would mean taking an image with the pi and sending it straight to the server for processing. You could use a simple protocol like xmlrpc to send image data to either a C++ or Python server. With this technique you should be able to send images at a decent frame rate and I'd hope your server could process at those rates in real time.

Comment: @figs, thanks for the reply! The server you are talking about will likely be a mobile phone in my scenario, which will have about the same processing power as the Pi. The mobile device will then need to send the OpenCV data it determines back to the Pi (it's a robotics application where the robot follows an object and happens to show it's view on a mobile device and the bounding box for the object).

Comment: Using a low-end device like a Pi for serious work like videoprocessing, and then using slow solutions like XML-RPC to send images encoded as text? While you care about performance? There's nothing wrong with XML-RPC when you're sending back the object coordinates. That's just 4 integers, and it doesn't matter whether you use 16 or 160 bytes for it - still one IP packet. But video is high-bandwidth.

Comment: @MSalters, anything you can suggest for what I am looking to do?

Comment: Well, I'd look for an object tracking solution using native code, and send the images as an mjpeg stream.

Comment: @faeophyta Hi!, I'm trying to do CMT on a Raspberry Pi from a moving robot. Did you have any success?

Comment: @dtbaker, unfortunately, I didn't - but that was a while ago. Maybe there's some new software that has been developed in the meantime.